# What to do with potential bugs?

Tags: documentation

Prompted by my [previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/how-can-i-resize-move-the-canvas-of-an-image-in-the-compositor), what should one do if they find something that *might* be a bug but aren't sure? Should these be reported? Ignored? Is there somewhere where there is a "tracker for potential bugs"?

Comment: Now why would you want to ignore a potential bug? ;)

Comment: @iKlsR I have accidentally reported several non-bugs lately (even after searching), and I was wondering if there is a alternative..

Comment: Ah, the answer on the question goes into depth about pretty much everything you need to consider.

Comment: @iKlsR I guess that does answer my question.. thanks