# How to rotate an image in compositor without cropping it?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have an image that I want to rotate in compositor, to mix it with another image later. But as you can see in the images attached, when I use the rotate node, the image gets cropped.

I could create a plane in 3DView and render it, but I would prefer a shorter solution inside the compositor.

Is there any way to extend the canvas of the image, so this operation can be done?

[image: non-rotated logo]
[image: rotated and cropped logo]

Comment: see this question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/how-can-i-resize-move-the-canvas-of-an-image-in-the-compositor