# How to move render to the left for space for text?

Tags: compositing-nodes

Currently, I have this:

[image: Current diagram]

However, I need space!:![image]

As you can see above, I need space to write text on the right, while keeping the background gradient. 
I had a look here: [How can I resize/move the "canvas" of an image in the compositor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/how-can-i-resize-move-the-canvas-of-an-image-in-the-compositor)
But it doesn't seem to work.

This is an example of my current compositing:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWjrQ.png]
.blend file: http://www.filedropper.com/xtruder22_1

Many Thanks

Comment: You could either do that in post processing (i.e. GIMP) or you could simply make the camera bigger and position the image to the left.

Comment: I'll see if there are any other answers.

Comment: @CharlesL Thanks loads, but I'll stick to the answer ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Transform node, for example:

[image]

Comment: Wait, did you make a text object in blender or did you edit the image? Thanks :)

Comment: @TimTimmy The text part was captured from yur quesion. :P you can either make it on the BG image. or put it in a separate render layer (or scene), then use another set of **Transform** and **Mix** (or **Alpha Over**) node to composite further (Another Transform node may be needed, too).