# Compositor renders video zoomed in

Tags: video, node-editor

So, I made a video, and what to edit it using nodes.

The viewer node shows the image as it should; however the Compositor node outputs the image zoomed in by 50%. Is there a reason to this? I have the same node connected to both the Compositor and Viewer nodes.

Comment: Is it possible you could upload a screenshot of your node setup?

Comment: well I have the pure video hooked up to the video.  It goes straight from the video node to the output node

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2376/599

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've just stumbled upon a unique feature of the compositor!

Yes, if your Scene>Dimensions>Resolution settings are not at 100% you won't see your full image.
The compositor doesn't automatically rescale images (or video) to fit the size used in the dimension's settings. When you render at 50% resolution, for example, it considers the composition to be half the number of pixels. The images in the image nodes get partially displayed because the picture size in pixels is not the same any more, but twice the size of the comp.

The workaround, if you want to work at a smaller resolutions, is to use a **scale node** with values that match your render settings. (But don't forget to turn it off a the end when you do the final render at full res!)
[image]

Comment: Well it works! Thanks for the helpful answer!

Comment: You're the best!

Answer (score 3):

Use a scale node and set the type from relative to render size. This automatically changes the resolution of the image to the render size.

You can then change the method of scaling to fit your needs, stretch will probably be decent in most cases, but if not, you can always try fit. Crop will look the same compared to what you're already getting.

[image: Basic example node setup]

Comment: Thanks! It works! What theme are you using?

Comment: I'm using graph by cogumelo softworks: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?328050-Theme-Graph-1-41-%28In-Trunk-Now!%29&highlight=graph+theme