# File output node outputs wrong image resolution

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have the node setup shown below.

The input image size is 8000px by 4000px. The scale node is supposedly reducing this to 800px by 600px.

If I hit render, and then manually save the output from the UV Image editor, I get exactly what I would expect (a nicely scaled image size 800px by 600px).

However, if I go to look at the file generated by the file output node, I get a different result. I get an image of size 8000px by 4000px with my 800px by 600px shrunk image in the centre of a massive black border.

How can I make the file output node output a properly scaled image?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots of the UV Image editor that show the rightly scaled image and the file output? What's your "canvas size" (I mean the values of Resolution in Render Tab)? Give a look to this related answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2404/15140

Comment: You can try to use **Crop** node after the scaling

Comment: @Carlo This doesn't look like the same issue to me. In this case, the composite node gives the expected result.

Comment: Also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19329/599

Comment: @gandalf3 true and that is why I initially dismissed that solution, however, I have tried it again this morning and mixing with a mask node does indeed resolve the issue with the file output. Thank you for your help everyone.