# Image in compositor is rendering white (or just a small portion of the original)

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am trying to add an image to a scene to be rendered. I am able to add the image in the compositor, but when I try and render the scene the image is mostly white with a few random pink and purple colors. I am using blender 2.79

This is a screen shot from cycles:

[image]

This is a screen shot from what gets rendered:

[image]

This is a screen shot from the 3D View camera view:

[image]

What is causing the render to be mostly white?

Comment: Is the image the same size (in pixels) as your blender scene?

Comment: @cegaton where do I check the cycles pixels size?

Comment: I'm guessing that your camera is way to close. With you cursor in the viewport press "0" to see your camera view.

Comment: @Dontwalk While in node editor if I push 0 nothing happens. If I switch to 3D View and push 0 I do not see anything. If I switch to render view and push 0 nothing happens.

Comment: While in 3D View, with your cursor in the viewport press "0" (*That is zero) to see the Camera Perspective.

Comment: @Dontwalk the image is in the compositor, not in 3d space.

Comment: @Dontwalk I added a screen shot of my camera perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you are loading and the blender scene are not the same size (in pixels)

Blender will not auto-size your images to fit within the compostion.

To know how big your image is press <kbd>N</kbd> in the UV/Image editor to bring out the side panel.

[image]

If you load an image that is larger than the composition, you will only see a portion of the image.

[image]

If you add a scale node and set it to fit, then your image will be scaled to fit within your composition.

[image]

Note that if the images are a **different aspect ratio** than the output, you have three choices:

**stretch**: deform the image to match within the aspect ratio of the container)

**Fit**: keep the images proportions but fill the remaining either with a transparent background or with black (if the "Use Alpha" option is unchecked)

or **Crop** Not stretching the image, resizing to fit vertically center cropping horizontally.

[image]

Comment: Read also this related post: [Compositor renders video zoomed in](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19328/compositor-renders-video-zoomed-in/19329#19329)