# How to render 2 scenes in the same animation

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I have two scenes, both with the same resolution (720x576).
My target is to get an animation with one scene in the upper part e the other in the lower part.

I tried using  compositing, but I couldn't get the result I expected.
[image: Target result and nodes]

I added a third scene with resolution (720x1152) as canvas.

It seems that the two images are enlarged and cropped to be resized to the resolution of the canvas (720x1152).

Any suggestion to avoid such a resizing or any other method to get the result I expected?

I tried also VSE, but I found a very similar problem.

Thanks

As suggested, I edit my question to explain the problem I have with the solutions of the two questions indicated below, that are similar or equal to mine. They do not avoid the resizing of the images when the images/animations are rendered, at least in my case.

Fig.1 below shows the best result I have got from the solution indicated in the first of the two questions, adjusting some of the parameters of the nodes.

The solution proposed in the second question is very similar to mine. It uses the transform node instead  the translate node. It seems to work in the preview, but when it is rendered, it shows similar problem as the others, at least in my case. Please see fig.2 below. Note the change in the input node where the images have been resized automatically.
[image: method 2 and 3]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I resize/move the "canvas" of an image in the compositor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/how-can-i-resize-move-the-canvas-of-an-image-in-the-compositor)

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52231/rendering-a-stereoscopic-image-in-blender-2-77/57870#57870